# Ajax Polling Get url returning data object not found

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to do an ajax polling to refresh my message div but I'm having the following error in my console:

```
 http://localhost/~userb/grind/dashboard/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
n.(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:4
update_chat @ convo.js:8
jquery.min.js:4 GET
```

Here's the snippet JS for the polling:

```
setInterval(update_chat, 2000);

    function update_chat()
    {
        var enquiryId = parseInt($('#messageMain').data('id'));

        $.get({url: '../includes/polling.php?id=' + enquiryId})
        .done(function(data) {
            $('#messageMain').html(data);
        });
    }
```

The html:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Chat
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <ul class="chat" id="messageMain" data-id="<?= $to_id ?>"> <!-- $to_id is what is used to get the messages -->
            <!-- all messages are queried from database here -->
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input id="btn-input" type="text" class="form-control input-sm" data-to="<?= $to_id ?>" placeholder="Type your message here...">
            <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="btn-chat">
                    Send</button>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Polling.php simply queries the Database and return the HTML that is used in the html above

Comment: Could you please post your HTML? Thanks !

Comment: @Christos Added HTML. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

change `$.get({url: '../includes/polling.php?id=' + enquiryId})` to `$.get('../includes/polling.php?id=' + enquiryId)`

the url goes directly as first param of .get()